# Checking if the "system" falls between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The Scenarion is DEMO001 system is booked from 10-Aug to 11-Aug by some user.

```
START_DATE     END DATE    SYSTEM
2016-08-10     2016-08-11  DEMO001
2016-09-05     2016-09-08  DEMO001
2016-08-08     2016-08-11  DEMO013
2016-08-16     2016-08-18  DEMO017
```

If Other user tries to book this system between these days . We have to check and pass 0 or 1.

I will get an input parameter

```
1) start_date as 2016-08-08 and 2016-08-15.
2) 2016-09-06 and 2016-09-07
3) 2016-08-08 and 2016-08-09
```

I have to write a PLSQL/SQL code to pass 0 because DEMO001 is falling between these start data and end date of the input else pass 1.

Kindly help.

Comment: How about if the two spans are not nested, but overlapping (starts before start, but does not end before end)?

Comment: Please include more sample data which shows want you want to achieve here.

Comment: @Thilo: Even in that case also 0. Basically user is not allowed to book this system if either of input date is falling between.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I have modified my question . kindly check and help

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( START_DATE, END_DATE, SYSTEM ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-08-10', DATE '2016-08-11', 'DEMO001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-09-05', DATE '2016-09-08', 'DEMO001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-08-08', DATE '2016-08-11', 'DEMO013' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-08-16', DATE '2016-08-18', 'DEMO017' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

With the bind variables `:start_date` and `:end_date` as the inputs:

```
SELECT system,
       MIN(
         CASE
         WHEN :end_date < start_date OR :start_date > end_date
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS can_book
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY system;
```

**Output**:

For the inputs `:start_date = DATE '2016-08-08'` and `:end_date = DATE '2016-08-15'`:

```
SYSTEM    CAN_BOOK
------- ----------
DEMO001          0 
DEMO013          0 
DEMO017          1
```

For the inputs `:start_date = DATE '2016-09-06'` and `:end_date = DATE '2016-09-07'`:

```
SYSTEM    CAN_BOOK
------- ----------
DEMO001          0 
DEMO013          1 
DEMO017          1
```

For the inputs `:start_date = DATE '2016-08-08'` and `:end_date = DATE '2016-08-09'`:

```
SYSTEM    CAN_BOOK
------- ----------
DEMO001          1 
DEMO013          0 
DEMO017          1
```

Comment: Nailed it :) Perfect

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, you want to disallow a booking if either the start or end date falls in between a given record.  You can just use a `CASE` expression for this.  I have hardcoded `2016-08-08` and `2016-08-15` as the start and end dates which you are using.

```
SELECT SYSTEM,
    CASE WHEN (DATE '2016-09-06' < START_DATE AND DATE '2016-09-07' < START_DATE) OR
              (DATE '2016-09-06' > END_DATE AND DATE '2016-09-07' > END_DATE)
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS allowBooking
FROM yourTable
```

Here is a link to a SQL Fiddle showing the query in action for the input range of `2016-08-08` to `2016-08-09`.  It clearly shows that all bookings are possible except for `DEMO013`.  I used MySQL but the logic should not change in going from MySQL to Oracle or vice-versa.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: it is failing for one scenario. I have added the second row in the table and another input. @Tim

Comment: I don't see why this is failing.

Comment: (2016-09-05>= '2016-09-06' AND '2016-09-05'<= '2016-09-07') OR (2016-09-08 >= '2016-09-06 AND '2016-09-08'<='2016-09-07'). See both condition fails. @Tim

Comment: I switched to using `BETWEEN` because it is very hard to read the `WHERE` clause as you have written it in your comment above.  It should work now.

Comment: If you use between it will fail for the first condition.  thatsy I am getting confused to write a genric conditon @Tim.

Comment: My logic is the same as saying if _both_ the start _and_ end date fall outside the range of a given record, then allow the booking.  This is the correct logic.  I think you are getting confused for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113986/discussion-between-mani-and-tim-biegeleisen).