# Scenario to allow update based on booking-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The Scenario is DEMO001 system is booked from 10-Aug to 11-Aug by the user.

```
START_DATE     END DATE    SYSTEM
2016-08-10     2016-08-11  DEMO001
2016-09-05     2016-09-08  DEMO001
2016-08-08     2016-08-11  DEMO013
2016-08-16     2016-08-18  DEMO017
```

Say if I get an input parameter

```
1) start date as 2016-08-08  and end date as 2016-08-11 I can allow 
2) start date as 2016-08-11  and end date as 2016-09-08 I cannot allow
3) start date as 2016-08-10   and end date as 2016-08-15 I can allow
3) start date as 2016-08-10   and end date as 2016-09-06 I cannot allow
```

If the user tries to update any of this system by extending or preponing the start or end date if no others booked between these days I will have to say 0 or 1  .

This is the extension to this scenario

[Checking if the "system" falls between two dates in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670170/checking-if-the-system-falls-between-two-dates-in-sql/37673546#37673546)

I tried modifying it the suggestion given there but not able to get it correctly. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Did the answers to your original question help at all?

Comment: Yes the suggestion provided by @MT0 is worked

Comment: What issue do you face when you try that? Can you please explain more?

Comment: @realspirituals: I dont face any issue. That is when creating a new booking this is for updating the existing booking. here user can extend or prepone the start/end date. So I have to check if nobody else have booked the same system during that period.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
WITH dates AS (

  -- input data (ranges)
  SELECT date '2016-08-08' as start_date,  date '2016-08-11' as end_date from dual union all
  SELECT date '2016-08-11',  date '2016-09-08' from dual union all
  SELECT date '2016-08-10',  date '2016-08-15' from dual union all
  SELECT date '2016-08-10',  date '2016-09-06' from dual
)

-- the query
SELECT d.start_date, d.end_date, 
       CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 
            THEN 'Disallow' ELSE 'Allow' 
            -- change the above line to => THEN 0 ELSE 1 <= if you prefer numbers
       END is_allowed
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 -- table1 holds booking data, eg DEMO0001 etc.
ON (d.Start_date <= t1.end_date)  and  (d.end_date >= t1.start_date ) 
    AND t1.system = 'DEMO001'
GROUP BY d.start_date, d.end_date
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: +1 and just used your answer to go inline with MTO's answer on the other ticket, so OP understands it easier

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a generic solution to distinguish if periods for a resource overlap in time.

Assuming those first four example lines are columns in a table named BOOKING, and you want to test a new date for the first booking, you can do this with queries like this:

```
CREATE TABLE booking( system_name  VARCHAR2( 10 )
                    , start_date   DATE
                    , end_date     DATE
                     );

INSERT INTO booking( system_name, start_date, end_date )
         VALUES ( 'DEMO001'
                , TO_DATE( '2016-09-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
                , TO_DATE( '2016-09-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
                 );
-- You only need this record, as you need to filter on the system name anyway
COMMIT;

SELECT CASE COUNT( 1 ) WHEN 0 THEN 'I can allow' ELSE 'I cannot allow' END
           AS outcome
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM booking old
             WHERE old.system_name = 'DEMO001'
               AND old.end_date > TO_DATE( '2016-08-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
               AND old.start_date < TO_DATE( '2016-08-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ));

SELECT CASE COUNT( 1 ) WHEN 0 THEN 'I can allow' ELSE 'I cannot allow' END
           AS outcome
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM booking old
             WHERE old.system_name = 'DEMO001'
               AND old.end_date > TO_DATE( '2016-08-11', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
               AND old.start_date < TO_DATE( '2016-09-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ));

SELECT CASE COUNT( 1 ) WHEN 0 THEN 'I can allow' ELSE 'I cannot allow' END
           AS outcome
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM booking old
             WHERE old.system_name = 'DEMO001'
               AND old.end_date > TO_DATE( '2016-08-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
               AND old.start_date < TO_DATE( '2016-08-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ));

SELECT CASE COUNT( 1 ) WHEN 0 THEN 'I can allow' ELSE 'I cannot allow' END
           AS outcome
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT 1
              FROM booking old
             WHERE old.system_name = 'DEMO001'
               AND old.end_date > TO_DATE( '2016-08-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
               AND old.start_date < TO_DATE( '2016-09-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ));
```

Of course the CASE Statement is just there to make the test outcome visually clear. If you want 0 and 1 for the opposite outcomes, just make it a "NOT EXIST"

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, you need to update existing booking dates of system only if no other date's clashes.

Please try below code, May it works from you.

```
    CREATE TABLE bookings (BookingId INT IDENTITY(1,1), StartDate Date, EndDate DATE, [SYSTEM] varchar(64));

    INSERT INTO bookings (StartDate, EndDate, [SYSTEM])
    VALUES
        ('2016-08-10', '2016-08-11', 'DEMO001'),
        ('2016-09-05', '2016-09-08', 'DEMO001'),
        ('2016-08-08', '2016-08-11', 'DEMO013'),
        ('2016-08-16', '2016-08-18', 'DEMO017');
```

[image: Booking Table]

```
    DECLARE 
        @ExistingBookingId INT = 1
        ,@NewStartDate DATE = '2016-08-10'
        ,@NewEndDate DATE = '2016-09-06';

    DECLARE @SystemCorrespondingToBookingId VARCHAR(64);

    SELECT @SystemCorrespondingToBookingId = [System]
    FROM bookings
    WHERE bookingId = @ExistingBookingId

    ;WITH AnotherBookingDatesOfSystem (StartDt, EndDt)
    AS
    (
        SELECT StartDate, EndDate
        FROM Bookings
        WHERE [System] = @SystemCorrespondingToBookingId
            AND BookingId <> @ExistingBookingId
    )

    SELECT ISNULL(MIN(
             CASE
             WHEN @NewEndDate < StartDt OR @NewStartDate > EndDt
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
             END
           ), 1) AS can_book
    FROM  AnotherBookingDatesOfSystem
```

It works for all given scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Full credit to @kordirko here, but just to make you understand with your familiar output model (as given by @MTO)

Bookings table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( START_DATE, END_DATE, SYSTEMS ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-08-10', DATE '2016-08-11', 'DEMO001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-09-05', DATE '2016-09-08', 'DEMO001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-08-08', DATE '2016-08-11', 'DEMO013' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-08-16', DATE '2016-08-18', 'DEMO017' FROM DUAL;
```

Query with bind variables systems, start_date, end_date

```
SELECT :systems, :start_date, :end_date, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 
            THEN 'I cannot Allow' ELSE 'I can Allow' 
        END result
FROM bookings t1 
WHERE ( :start_date <= t1.end_date) AND (:end_date >= t1.start_date ) 
    AND t1.systems = :systems
GROUP BY :start_date, :end_date;
```

Output:

```
1) DEMO001  2016-08-08  2016-08-11  -> I can Allow
2) DEMO001  2016-08-11  2016-09-08  -> I cannot Allow
3) DEMO001  2016-08-10  2016-08-15  -> I can Allow
4) DEMO001  2016-08-10  2016-09-06  -> I cannot Allow
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try this based on the sql statement suggested to you referred in the OP link:

```
SELECT system, min(can_book) can_book
FROM (
       SELECT system,
         CASE
         WHEN (NOT(start_date BETWEEN :start_Date AND :end_date) 
               AND NOT(end_date BETWEEN :start_Date AND :end_date)) 
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS can_book
FROM   table_name
)GROUP BY system;
```